# How to resolve some inconsistencies in the mathematical model for the narrowband fading channel?

Tags: fading-channel, quadrature, channel

I am reading **Wireless Communications by Andrea Goldsmith**. There the author mentions that for narrow band channel the received signal can be given as:
$$r(t)=\text{Re} \left\{u(t)\text{exp}(j2\pi f_ct)\left(\sum_{n}\alpha_n(t)\text{exp}(-j\phi_n(t))\right) \right\}$$
where $u(t)$ is the low pass equivalent signal for $s(t)$
$\alpha_n(t)$ is the attenuation due to $n\text{th}$ resolvable component, and $\phi_n(t)$ is the phase term for the $n\text{th}$ resolvable component.

She now assumes $s(t)$ to be just an unmodulated carrier with random phase offset $\phi_0$ and writes:
$$s(t)=\text{Re}\{\text{exp}(j2\pi f_c t+\phi_0)\}=\cos(2\pi f_c t+\phi_0)$$
and **says that this is narrow band for any any delay spread $T_m$** for narrowband $B_u<{T_m}^{-1}$ where $B_u$ is the bandwidth of the signal.
**Why is it so? Is it because $\cos(2\pi f_c t+\phi_0)$ has just one frequency?**

Moving further, the author writes the received signal as:

\begin{align}
r(t)&=\text{Re}\{\text{exp}(j2\pi f_ct)(\sum_{n}\alpha_n(t)\text{exp}(-j\phi_n(t)))\}\\
&=r_I(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)-r_Q(t)\sin(2\pi f_c t)
\end{align}

where she says

$$r_I(t)=\sum_n \alpha_n(t) \cos(\phi_nt)$$ and
$$r_Q(t)=\sum_n \alpha_n(t) \sin(\phi_nt)$$

**But when I tried to solve I got**
**$$r_Q(t)=-\sum_n \alpha_n(t) \sin(\phi_nt)$$**
**I am totally confused about how the calculations are happening? Am I ignoring the negative sign**? Can somebody please help me out.

Comment: The minus sign on your $r_Q$ is in the author’s definition of the whole signal.

Comment: @Peter K. Thanks. Just one more question why the author says that $s(t)=cos(2\pi f_c t+\phi_0)$ is narrow band for any any delay spread?

Comment: @Peter K. Also, I am unable to get your comment that "minus sign on your $r_Q$ is in the author’s definition of the whole signal" as the final result for me turns out to be "$r_I(t)cos(2\pi f_ct)+r_Q(t)sin(2\pi f_ct)$"

Comment: @UserHuffmann for the first question, yes, the $B$ of $s(t)$ is infinitesimal and, therefore, $B < T_m^{-1}$ for any $T_m$.

Comment: @UserHuffmann for the second question, just define $\theta_n(t) = -\phi_n(t)$ you will get the final form of the author. As $\phi_n(t)$ and $\theta_n(t)$ have the same stochastic properties, substituing $\theta_n(t)$ for $\phi_n(t)$ does not change the model. IMO, the author wanted to come up with their definition $r_Q(t)$ as this is a common choice for the so-called quadrature component.